# Why is the bone in Unity moving without me moving the mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used this code to rotate the bone when I move the mouse in the x direction:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shootscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform bone_2;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPos=bone_2.localEulerAngles;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos=Input.mousePosition;
        float dx = mousePos.x - Screen.width / 2;
        float angle = startPos.z+dx*100f*Time.deltaTime;
        bone_2.localEulerAngles=new Vector3(0,0, angle);
    }
}
```

It is working, but when I don't move the mouse, the bone is shaking.

Why is the bone in Unity moving without me moving the mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
float dx = mousePos.x - Screen.width / 2;
float angle = (startPos.z) + (dx*100f*Time.deltaTime);
```

I think dx is never zero, therefore it is always affecting the angle in the Update. You can try clamping the dx value and set it to zero if its under the threshold.

**Example**:

```
float dx = mousePos.x - Screen.width / 2;
float threshold = 0.1f; // Adjust the threshold value as needed

// Clamp dx to zero if it is below the threshold
if (Mathf.Abs(dx) < threshold)
{
    dx = 0f;
}

float angle = startPos.z + (dx * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of code for clamping the dx value and setting it to zero?

Comment: It is still not moving correctly. Is this code that I provided the only way to rotate the bone using mouse movements? Is there a better way of doing that?